# Can't mount /mnt/x after reboot

Tags: debian, uuid, mount, fstab, blkid

After rebooting my server, I saw through nagios that my /mnt/gimli was only reachable on read-only mode. But I need it to be writable because some backups go there.

To have in in rw mode, I tried unmounting and remounting /mnt/gimli, but got the error : "mount: can't find UUID=f1953589-1c80-466b-91ad-6cfed92a4c38"

When I do df -hT, I can see its not mounted anymore, but I can't remount it.

I don't really know what to try since it's an important part of the sever and I don't want to mess it all up.

Here's the output of blkid

```
/dev/vda1: UUID="d71f1001-8e5e-416a-b3f1-16000626ebd9" TYPE="ext2" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="00065439-01"
/dev/vda2: UUID="a656b9da-cc00-46e3-ae1e-be47c4ff6061" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00065439-02"
/dev/vda3: UUID="b1989379-cd66-4fce-97d3-ec9cb73d2d02" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00065439-03"
/dev/vda5: UUID="89b7401f-f8eb-43cb-af11-a8a9a1811080" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00065439-05"
/dev/vdb1: UUID="d8c920ae-69e2-4fde-9f46-a897bb680234" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="87b503d3-01"
/dev/vdc1: UUID="cc668f71-c51e-4b92-aae7-871b3bae9c16" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7f7cf5dd-01"
```

And the output of cat /etc/fstab :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a656b9da-cc00-46e3-ae1e-be47c4ff6061 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#d71f1001-8e5e-416a-b3f1-16000626ebd9   /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda5 during installation
/dev/vda5               /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
/dev/vda3   none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/vdc1   /mnt/home       ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/vdb1   /mnt/data       ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=f1953589-1c80-466b-91ad-6cfed92a4c38       /mnt/gimli      ext4    _netdev,defaults        0       0
#/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
#/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
# /dev/sdb1  /mnt/data            ext4    defaults        0       2
#UUID=6c9a4b04-fd18-4682-a174-a0d158315be4   /mnt/home            ext4    defaults        0       2
#gimli:/volume1/backups /mnt/gimli  nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192   0   0
#gimli:/volume1/serveurs    /mnt/sauvegarde nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192   0   0
#gimli:/volume1/versioning  /mnt/versioning nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192   0   0
#gimli:/volume1/old /mnt/old    nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192   0   0
UUID=d71f1001-8e5e-416a-b3f1-16000626ebd9   /boot   ext2    defaults    0   2
```

So, I would like to be able to remount /mnt/gimli as it was, and would also like to know why it's the only one appearing as UUID on my fstab, and not as /dev/xxx

Does someone know how I could do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this.

Since it was a Synology, I needed the iscsid service to run, which was missing.

I've restarted open-iscsi which wasn't running, and it was this service which ran iscsis.service.